# Suppress sound for other logged in users?

Tags: notifications, user-account, sound-volume

If I have two users logged in, the desktop is only shown for the active user, but the sounds from apps on the inactive user's session are still heard.

I want to not hear those sounds. What should I do?

I haven't been able to find this by searching on Google.

Comment: That's curious - on my iMac I am logged in and active with 2 of my kids also logged in and there is no cross-over issue like that.

Comment: Really? I can hear when someone writes to the other user's web chat accounts

Comment: Really. One son leaves his gaming session live and I then take over and do stuff like skype and no odd crossover or chat happens at all.